# Show that $f_n(z)=z^n$ converges locally uniformly on $|z|<1$ but not uniformly(?)

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

Show that $f_n(z)=z^n$ converges locally uniformly on $|z|<1$ but not uniformly.

I am really confused. I saw a seemingly reliable reference stating that $z^n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $\{|z|<1\}$ but it does converge uniformly on $\{|z|\le r,r<1\}$. What is the nuance between the two former sets? With $r_n<1,r_n\to 1$, shouldn't one conclude that $f_n(z)$ uniformly converges on $\{|z|<1\}$? And besides, this source tells me what I have to prove for Homework is disproved, which really makes it more frustrating.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Uniform convergence on a set means that for each choice of $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ that works for every $x$ in the set.   But now you don't have one set, but an increasing sequence of sets, namely the sets $\{ z \, | \, |z| \leq r_n\}$ (where $r_n$ is your sequence of radii tending to $1$).  Now as you note, you have uniform convergence on each of these sets, so given $\epsilon,$ there is $\delta$ that works.  But this $\delta$ works just for $z$ s.t. $|z| \leq r_n$, so maybe we should denote it $\delta_n$.  Now what can happen (and what *does* happen in your situation) is that

Comment: $\delta_n \to 0$, and so you *can't* find a $\delta$ that works simultaneously for all $z$ lying in the union of the sequence of sets, i.e. for all $z$ with $|z| < 1$.

Comment: @RRL: No, I wasn't, but looking back at my comment I realized I wrote $\delta$ when I should have written $N$.

Comment: @tracing. I see that now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have pointwise convergence to $0$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| < 1$.

Uniform convergence requires that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ independent of $z$ such that $n \geqslant N$ implies $|z^n - 0| < \epsilon$ for every $z \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}.$ This is impossible when $z$ can be arbitrarily close to the boundary of that disc.

Given any positive integer $N$ take $z_n = (1 - 1/n)$ where $n > N$. Recall that  $(1-1/n)^n \to e^{-1}$ and we must have $(1 - 1/n)^n > e^{-1}/2$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Hence, we can find some $n > N$ such that

$$|z^n -0|= |z|^n  = (1-1/n)^n > e^{-1}/2,$$

in violation of uniform convergence.

With the definition in mind try to show yourself that convergence is uniform on any compact disc $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leqslant r\}$ with $r < 1$.

Comment: What as for **locally** uniform convergence? This is what I initially look at and it was said that the $f_n$ isn't. What should be the refutation of that?

Comment: I am sorry, it didn't regard the issue locally.

Comment: My mistake...I now understand your answer

Comment: My understanding of local uniform convergence is given any $w$ in the open unit disc $D_1(0)$ there exists $r.>0$ such that $D_r(w) \subset D_1(0)$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly on $D_r(w)$.  So I first tried to answer for you why convergence is not uniform on the open unit disc.  Hopefully you see that part now.

Comment: Can you see why convergence is locally uniformly convergent?

Comment: Suppose I show uniform convergence for $\{|z|<r:r\le 1\}$, then for any $w,|w|<1$ does it already follow that a desired $r$ exists? I mean, is it legitimate to do this that way?

Comment: That is the right thinking. First convergence is uniform on any disc centered at $0$ with radius $r < 1$ since $|z|^n < r^n$. And $r^n \to 0$.  We can find one $N$ that works for every $z$ in that closed disc.

Comment: If $z \in D_r(w)$ where $w \in D_1(0)$ and $D_r(w) \subset D_1(0)$ then there must be some $k< 1$ such that $|z| < k$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For each $0<r<1$, the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,,\,|z|\leq r\}$ is compact, while $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,,\,|z|<1\}$ is not.

Comment: So what I am required to prove is unprovable?